# SQL Query to Get Count of Order ,Download app and Sign up in optimize way

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `Partner` table :

| Partner Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

My `Customer` table:

| Customer Id | Name | Sign_up_Referral_By | Download_Referral_By | Order_Referral_By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | DEW |  | 1 |  |
| 112 | ERU | 2 |  | 2 |

Note :

Customer table columns `Sign_up_Referral_By`, `Download_Referral_By`, `Order_Referral_By` are foreign keys referencing the `Partner` table's `Partner id` column.

I want to get count of number of download, sign up by partner referral Id :

My expected output is

| Partner Id | Name | Sign up Referral By Count | Download Referral By count | Order Referral By count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |  | 1 |  |
| 2 | xyz | 1 |  | 1 |

I have tried this code in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    [partner].USER_GUID, [partner].NAME,
    COUNT([customer].SIGN_UP_REFERAL_BY) Sign_Up_Count,
    COUNT([customer].APP_DOWNLOAD_REFERAL_BY) Download_Count,
    COUNT([customer].ORDER_REFERAL_BY) Order_Count  
FROM
    TBL_CUSTOMER_DETAILS [customer]
RIGHT JOIN
    TBL_PARTNER_DETAILS [partner] ON [customer].SIGN_UP_REFERAL_BY = [partner].USER_GUID 
                                  OR [customer].APP_DOWNLOAD_REFERAL_BY = [partner].USER_GUID 
                                  OR [customer].ORDER_REFERAL_BY = [partner].USER_GUID 
GROUP BY 
    [partner].Partner_Id, [partner].NAME;
```

But I'm getting a wrong output; can anyone point out what's wrong here or any optimize way to get count download, sign up and order by using partner id by above table schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to unpivot and then reaggregate:

```
select v.partnerid, p.name, 
       sum(is_signup), sum(is_download), sum(is_order)
from customer c cross apply
     (values (Sign_up_Referral_By, 1, 0, 0),
             (Download_Referral_By, 0, 1, 0),
             (Order_Referral_By, 0, 0, 1)
     ) v(partnerid, is_signup, is_download, is_order) join
     partner p
     on v.partnerid = p.partnerid
group by v.partnerid, p.name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afe2565c0d7e68486b28e846d93cefaa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I am getting the same output as my query which I have tried. And I don't have is download, Is sign up flags to sum. In my `customer` table  have `Sign_up_Referral_By, Download_Referral_By, Order_Referral_By` columns which store `partner id`

Comment: @Beginner . . . This is returning `0`s instead of `NULL`s but is otherwise the results you want.